# Why is UITextField not allowing me to add border color?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have the below method which should add border color to a uitextfield but for some reason, it does not add the border color, although it does successfully get added to the view a can be typed in.

```
func setupSearchBar() {
    searchField.frame = CGRect(x: 4, y: 6.5, width: 366.58, height: 42)
    searchField.layer.cornerRadius = searchField.frame.height/2
    topBackgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 0.35
    searchField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0/225, green: 0/225, blue: 0/225, alpha: 0.49).cgColor
    searchField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    view.addSubview(searchField)
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add a ````borderwidth```` to the ````searchField````

Comment: I second that. Also, what is topBackgroundView? And why are you increasing its border width?

Comment: @SamKing this was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search field borderWidth is defaulting to 0. Try:

```
func setupSearchBar() {
    searchField.frame = CGRect(x: 4, y: 6.5, width: 366.58, height: 42)
    searchField.layer.cornerRadius = searchField.frame.height/2
    topBackgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 0.35
    searchField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0/225, green: 0/225, blue: 0/225, alpha: 0.49).cgColor
    searchField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 // <- Add here
    searchField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    view.addSubview(searchField)
}
```